# Settings Google Chrome's search to American results

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Google Chrome search using google.com rather than google.com.hk?](https://superuser.com/questions/293916/how-to-make-google-chrome-search-using-google-com-rather-than-google-com-hk)

I'm in Germany, and when search using the omni bar, I automatically get results from google.de. How do I change that to google.com?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `chrome://chrome/settings/searchEngines`.
2. In the Google entry, replace `google.de` by `google.com`.

Comment: You *might* still need to change these settings on the Google website as well. Not too sure though.

Comment: I tried that, I still get redirected to the German website.

Comment: @lowerkey: I assumed "normal" Google search already worked as intended. Visiting http://google.com/ncr once should take care of that. If your OS's default language isn't English, you might also want to adjust the settings in http://google.com/preferences (Languages tab). You have to allow cookies or none of this will work.