# Force Google Chrome Browser to use google.com

Tags: google-chrome, localization

I have a U.S.-based google account, but I am currently in India. I always want `google.com` search results, not `google.co.in`.

I go to `google.com`, but I get immediately redirected to `google.co.in`.

Sometimes I am given the option to "use google.com" at the bottom right. I do that, but it doesn't stick. The next time I go, I get redirected.

I stay logged in to Google 24/7 with my U.S.-based account.

**Edit**: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/293919/339009) worked for me. (I also  disabled the `My Location` feature as noted in the comments.)

Comment: try this  https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/179386?hl=en

Comment: So I assume you have tried [this](http://www.google.com/ncr) correct? Have you tried setting your [location](https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en&fg=1#location) to something other than India and have made sure your language [settings](https://www.google.com/preferences#languages) are set to English?  You should also disable the `My Location` feature.

Comment: My answer on the page you linked to should work.

Comment: @ramhound - disabling plus [clicking](https://www.google.com/ncr) plus making sure that I wasn't cookie-clearing worked - many thanks

Comment: @Ramhound Maybe you should edit my answer on the linked page to include that extra information, as I am not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: What answer...?

Comment: @paradroid I can add a comment to your answer, but first I want to really be sure that it wasn't carelessness on my part (active 'no caching' with console open during web development or other settings-clearings). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re searching on a local Google domain like google.fr, but prefer to search on google.com instead, follow these steps:

Visit your local google domain, like google.fr.
Click the gray Google.com link in the bottom right corner of the page.
Note: If you clear your cookies, you’ll need to repeat these steps to search on google.com.

If you're seeing a Google domain that doesn't match the country you're in, we might be incorrectly detecting your IP address. For example, you could see Google.com.au instead of Google.co.nz. If this is happening to you, report the IP problem.

Comment: This no longer works?  http://superuser.com/a/293919/8972